# Issues with Running Rsync Command

Tags: linux, perl, unix, rsync

I am using rsync in my perl script.

I am using the following command:

```
rsync -av /view/pore/Personel Address.txt /home/myserver/Personel Address.txt
```

It fails giving me error as:

> building file list .. rsync: link_stat "/view/pore/Personel Address.txt: failed: No such file or directory

If I rename the file to `Personel_Address.txt`, it works fine.

Can anyone please help me with the correct command to be used. I cannot rename the text file to `Personel_Address`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a backslash before the space like this:

```
rsync -av /view/pore/Personel\ Address.txt /home/myserver/Personel\ Address.txt
```

It's usually nicer not to have spaces in filenames though.
If you have a space the program thinks that it is the next parameter that it takes, but with  the \ it cancels it out and passes the whole string as one parameter.

Comment: Hi Thanks,It worked that way..But my script copies 1000 of files recursively , I need to know if we can use any options with rsync command because i will not be able to hardcode the stuff

Comment: Good! You can accept the answer with the checkmark button to the left of the question. :)
You can most likely also make it work with citation marks around the parameters, like:
rsync -av "/view/pore/Personel Address.txt" "/home/myserver/Personel Address.txt"

Comment: If everything is in the same folder you can use the -r parameter.

Answer (score 2):

the problem here is that you need to escape the space. something like

> `rsync -av /view/pore/Personel\ Address.txt /home/myserver/Personel\ Address.txt`

instead of simply

> `rsync -av /view/pore/Personel Address.txt /home/myserver/Personel Address.txt`

should work the way you want.